# Lua: Split code into separate files

Tags: lua

I am writing a lua program to control a scan unit. But due the complexity of the program keeping the code in one file is too confusing. Can I split it into separate files? If I can, how?

Comment: You can separate them into several files. However, bear in mind that if the functions are local, you will not be able to access them from a different file.

Comment: Do I need something like an import of that files, like in java?

Comment: see the answer.

Comment: Have you at least google it?

Comment: Sure i googled it, but the results I got were pretty confusion, some of them stating you need a require-statement, some say you don´t. So if you don´t need this require-statement how could the script seperate two functions that are named the same?

Comment: You can use either `require 'filename'` or `loadfile 'filename.lua'()` to include code from another lua source file. Former is prefer but you can use the latter too if you need more precise control over how things get included. If you want more detailed answer, show us the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file1.lua

```
function add(a, b)
    return a + b
end
```

file2.lua

```
function subtract(a, b)
    return a - b
end
```

file3.lua

```
function DoSomething(a,b)
    return add(a, b), subtract(a, b)
end
```

Keep in mind that functions are not local to files, therefore, they will be in global table and will be accessed by other files. If you use `local function a` in one file, then in another file, you will not access the `local function a`.

In short words, if you dont use `local` keyword, you can access the variables, functions from other files.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "include". As long as the functions or variables are in global table, they are accessible from different files, unless you specify a different table. The conceptually equivalent of `static` keyword in C++ is `local` in Lua. Also take a look at greatwolf's comment.

Comment: How do you put a directive in a file that causes Lua to read that file as code so that the statements are executed and the functions are available for use?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: greatwolf's comment answers your query very well.